# Android app can't find an AVD target to run on in "Run Configuration"

Tags: target, android-virtual-device

I am new to Eclipse and to Android. I successfully completed the "Hello Android" tutorial. It compiled, downloaded and ran fine on both of the two AVD's I created ... "first_avd" and "second_avd". To do this, I highlight the application, right click, select "Run As" --> "Run Configurations...", --> "Target", both AVDs are shown, I select one or the other, and it works.

I then started on the Notepad tutorial. But I can't run it as above because "Run Configurations..." --> "Target" displays neither of my AVDs; it is greyed out and says "No AVD available".

However, If I just select "Run As" --> "Android Application", "first_avd" seems to be automatically  selected, the application loads and runs. -or- if either "first_avd" or "second_avd" is *already* launched, the application will load and run on the launched AVD. So the aplication works fine!

I'm probably missing something really simple here, but I've been horsing around with this all day, checked Google until I can't figure out any more questions to ask, with no results. Both AVDs have Platform 4.0 and APILevel 14. Both "Hello Android" and "Notepadv1" include  in their Manifest. I should be able to select an AVD to run "Notepadv1", but can't.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Go to the AVD manager and edit the VD so that it uses the same API level as your project target's API level

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to android development too and i ran into a similar problem recently.

When you create an Android project it asks you for a 'target' and you choose one of the available versions (android 3.0, 4.0.3, etc). If the version you choose is higher than the ones running on your AVD than it will tell you that it cannot find any.

so check that you have an AVD running that version, and if not than create one by using the ADV manager.

that worked for me.

Comment: pete@pete:~/.android/avd$ cat first_avd.ini 
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:14
pete@pete:~/.android/avd$ cat second_avd.ini 
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:14

Comment: on the Package Explorer on eclipse, right click your project and go to properties, look under "Android" and check what version of android you have checked. Now go to your AVD manager and make sure you have a corresponding AVD, and if not create one.